# Removing caulk on painted wall

Tags: caulk

My husband painted our daughters bedroom with one large strip horizontal stripe  around the room.  To make the lines even on our textured wall he used caulk.  How do I get rid of the caulk lines so I can paint the room one color?

Comment: i've seen this method recommended for painting, but they generally say to remove the caulk *immediately* after painting.

Answer (score 2):

Just peel or scape it off.  Depending on what type of product was used, it might come off cleanly or it might not.  Worst case is you will need to patch any damaged parts of the wall, prime and repaint (which you will need to do anyways!).

Comment: And smack your husband.  Caulk is a sealant, not a border for painting.  They make painters tape for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

3M makes a [caulking remover](http://www.truevalue.com/product/12-Pint-Caulk-Remover/25367.uts), it works pretty good- softens up caulking overnight. May damage the wall just as much as mechanical removal though.